# Intent-Filter within a Service

Tags: android, service, intentfilter

I have the following inside my manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".Rotate" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"> 

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

However the holding down the search key doesn't activate `SEARCH_LONG_PRESS` anymore. Before I replaced `<activity>` with `<service>` it use to show two options when long pressing the search key, one was my app the other was Google Voice Search... now it's just Google Voice Search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `SEARCH_LONG_PRESS` is not used for services. It is used for activities. Each use of the `Intent` system (`startActivity()`, `startService()`, `sendBroadcast()`) is independent of the others. You cannot have a service respond to `startActivity()`, for example.