# Intent Filter not calling onReceive for USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I have declared an intent filter for `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` in the constructor of a `MyDialogFragment` and registered/unregistered it in the fragment's `onResume` and `onPause` methods. `MyReceiver` extends `BroadcastReceiver` in an inner class to receive the `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` intent. See following code:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

     private Context context;
     private IntentFilter usbIntentFilter;
     private MyReceiver myReceiver;

     MyDialogFragment(Context context) {
        usbIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED);
        myReceiver = new myReceiver();
        this.context = context;
     }


     @Override
     public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();

          // Register broadcast receiver
         context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, usbIntentFilter);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
          super.onPause();

          // Unregister broadcast receiver
          context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
     }

     class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("MyApp","Called USB receiver");

        }
     }
}
```

However, the `onReceive` method of `MyReceiver` never gets called when I attach a USB accessory. Furthermore, when I change the intent to

```
usbIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
```

the `onReceive` method of `MyReceiver` does get called. So my question is: why does it work when I detach the accessory, but not when I attach the accessory?

Comment: Have you included required permissions in your **AndroidManifest.xml**?

Comment: I have `<uses-feature   android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />`.  But this is not permissions. Do I need those too?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#manifest

Comment: Thnx. But I believe that details how to set up the manifest so that a prompt can be given to user to open the app when you attach a device. I just want to listen for when any usb device is attached when the app is already running. Therefore, as far as I understand, since I'm registering the receiver using `context.registerReceiver` I should only require `<uses-feature       android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"/>` in the manifest.

Comment: Looks like someone else fiound something similar https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_h5giLPFir0 It seems odd that I receive the broadcast for detaching the USB, but not for attaching it. There's either a reason for this, or it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that `USB_ACESSORY_ATTACHED` intent never actually gets through to the activity, see SO question :

[Android 3.1 USB-Host - BroadcastReceiver does not receive USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981736/android-3-1-usb-host-broadcastreceiver-does-not-receive-usb-device-attached/9814826#9814826)

You have to work with the `onResume` method that is called indirectly by `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED`. I have to say, this isn't clear in the Android documentation, and I question its implementation.