# What Intent Action does the Android System Broadcast when USB Accessory Attached

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I have a service that I'm using to monitor the connectivity of an attached USB accessory. The service has no problem picking up intents with `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED`, but does not pick up intents with `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED`.

The same is true for an activity, i.e., the activity never actually seems to get the intent with action `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED`, but instead gets a `MAIN` intent action which calls the activity's `onResume` method. While not ideal, this behaviour does allow a work around in an activity by coding up the `onResume` method appropriately, see: [Intent Filter not calling onReceive for USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770788/intent-filter-not-calling-onreceive-for-usb-accessory-attached)

Unfortunately, I do not have an `onResume` method in a service, and so can not use the work around that can be used in activities. However, the system must be broadcasting something when a USB accessory is attached: what is this intent, and is there anyway a service can receive this intent?

It appears that Android is implementing a strange methodology for broadcasting USB attach/detach intents. It just doesn't make sense why I should be able to pick up detached events so easily and not attached events. Could this be a bug, or poor implementation.