# BroadcastReceiver for usb accessory message

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a FTDI udb custom device attached to my tablet and I can connect to him but I want to ignore the message

Allow the app "MyAPP" to access the USB device ?
[checkmark]Use by default for this USB device
Cancel            OK

I am trying to run a BroadcastReceiver  but the message is before the reciver is getting the message, can anyone advice why

note: my device is rooted.
my device will be a panel that a user is not over there to click.

my code is:

manifest:

```
     <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

        <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />  
        </intent-filter>


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" >
        </meta-data>

    </activity>
   <receiver android:name=".LaunchReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 
</application>
```

LaunchReceiver class:

```
    public class LaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("UUU", "on launcher receive");
     }
}
```

the problem is that the message is before my app start's

an other problem is that I dont know where to create the LaunchReceiver class because I want him before every thing starts.

can anyone advice?

thank you !!

Comment: "the problem is that the message is before my app start's" where you called LaunchReceiver?

Comment: in the onCreate of MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states). 

[image]
When you called LauncherReceiver in `onCreate` you called it before app started. That why you have message  before your app started.

Comment: Thank you! I switched the usb start connection to onResume() if it is null but still my message about usb is before the onCreate()

Comment: Create Log.i in every method and post your LogCat

Comment: I am trying to create a clear logcat but I am missing something in the understanding how it works (I am new in android) who is putting this message I or the system as soon as I put the .USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED in the intent-filter?

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to search by tag use`tag:YourTag`. So to create LogCat use: `Log.i("YourTag", "xxx");` of course instead of **xxx** use name of method. That will help you understand problem and Life cycle

Comment: I understand but the usb message that I would like to ignore is coming before any message that means before the onCreate, can it be?

Comment: I changed the order of the <intent-filter> and now I am in the onCreat before the message

Comment: Okey, just next time be more precise:) An If my answer was helpful, you learned something like it/accept.

Comment: what is loading before onCreate() because I don't see any Log line in my TAG before the USB connection message for a minute it looked to me that I do see or maybe I did see:( but didn't change anything and I don't see any log before the USB message, pleas advice

Answer (score 0):

Remove intent-filter and meta-data from activity tag. You must also to add meta-data to reciver tag (I believe the meta-data is required for USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED action). With that, the message only will be recived for LaunchReceiver.

Other solution is move reciver tag to before activity tag, for the message is received first by LaunchReceiver and after for MainActivity.

The LaunchReceiver will be instantiated for SO when event occurs, put it in the root proyect package.

I hope I've help you and excuse my bad english. Greetings from venezuela.

Answer (score 0):

excuse me, I was wrong in my previous answer... I was cheking if USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED works in the reciver and services, but apparently it is not so. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098332/usb-accessory-catch-usb-accessory-attached-by-intent-filter-of-serviceory-attached-by-intent-filter-of-service) have the same problem. They say they say the USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED and USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED actions no works in the reciver, only works in de activity. I could check this answer with may proyect.

Newly excuse my bad english and excuse me for bad answer. Regards